# card game can't put empty space between cards

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am building a simple card game, and I have a line in the bottom of the cards like this:

[image]

when I click on the card and it matches the number the card disappears and it is the expected behaviour. The issue is that when it disappears it doesn't leave an empty space, it just occupy the empty space with the next card, as this:

[image]

** I am doing the component this way:**

```
<template>
  <div class="towerLine-wrapper">
    <div class="towerLine">
      <img
        :style="{'left': index * 83 + 'px'}"
        v-for="(line, index) in towerLine"
        @click="removeCard(line, index)"
        :key="line.number"
        class="towerLine__image"
        :src="line.src"
        alt="">
    </div>
    <tri-pack :deckCards="deckCards" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import triPack from '../triPack/triPack.vue'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      currentCard: {}
    }
  },
  props: {
    towerLine: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    deckCards: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeCard (line, index) {
      this.getCurrentCard()
      const firstCardCheck = this.currentCard.type === 1 && line.type === 13
      const lastCardCheck = this.currentCard.type === 13 && this.currentCard.type === 1
      const otherCardCheck = (line.type + 1 === this.currentCard.type) || (line.type - 1 === this.currentCard.type)
      if ((firstCardCheck || lastCardCheck) || otherCardCheck) {
        this.towerLine.splice(index, 1)
        this.$store.commit('setCurrentCard', line)
      }
    },
    getCurrentCard () {
      this.currentCard = this.$store.getters.getCurrentCard
    }
  },
  components: {
    triPack
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  .towerLine {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: -90px;
    left: -40px;

    &__image {
      width: 80px;
      height: 100px;

      &:not(:first-child) {
        position: absolute;
      }
    }
  }
</style>
```

I know that it doesn't work, because when I remove a card the index change and when it multiplies it gives the same position to occupy the empty space, but how can I solve this problem?

Any help?

Comment: I'm thinking of several solutions: you could either keep the data and give a special flag to your card after it's been removed to keep the dom element to avoid worrying about the positioning. You could find a way to position cards differently: position absolute or css grid could help you.

Comment: i thougth about css grid but it has bad support in IE

Comment: I think the flag might be an easy way out, give a type -1 to your card if it's removed and create a special styling for removed card